# How differentiation of $\log x$ a negative number.

Tags: calculus

We know that $(\log x)'= 1/x$ for $x>0$.
Now when we take $x$ as negative, then $(\log -x)'= 1/(-x) * (-1)=1/x$. Here $x<0$.Can someone please explain why we are getting two answers.

Comment: **What** "two" answers? And what does that $\;x<1\;$ thing mean?

Comment: Again, what *two* answers?

Comment: i mean to say let x=-2 Therefore 2=-(-2) I.e -x.Now as in answer (log-x)'=1/x=-1/2

Comment: also log-x is positive

Comment: Try to sketch the graph of $\;\log(-x)\;,\;\;x<0\;$ . You will realize at once that at each point its gradient or derivative is the exact additive inverse of the usual function $\;\log x\;,\;\;x>0\;$ , and thus what you get is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plot the graphs of $y=\log x$ for $x>0$ and $y=\log(-x)$ for $x<0$. You'll see they're reflections of each other in the $y$-axis.

In particular, $\log x$ is increasing for all $x > 0$, and $\log(-x)$ is decreasing for all $x<0$.

Thus it makes sense that the derivative be positive when $x>0$ and negative when $x<0$... and indeed, $\frac{1}{x} > 0$ when $x>0$ and $\frac{1}{x} < 0$ when $x<0$.

Answer (score 3):

You've just proved that $\bigl(\ln\lvert x\rvert\bigr)'=\dfrac1x $.

Answer (score 0):

Logarithm of negative numbers are not defined. Have a look at this
([Value of Logarithm of negative number](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/207660/value-of-logarithm-of-negative-number))

Comment: But he's not taking the $\log$ of a negative number.

Comment: the first answer.i want to know how

Comment: When looking at the graph how can you say its negative

Comment: gentlemen I am not satisfied is someone there

Comment: Thanks a lot I understood it.Next time i will try it myself also.again thanks a lot.